# Second enter critical section

Tags: operating-system, wait, critical-section

Is this code correct?

I have just one thread and I enter critical section second time without leaving it and I expect that I will wait indefinitely but I enter without waiting.

```
int var = 0;
CRITICAL_SECTION cs;    
InitializeCriticalSection(&cs);

EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
var = 10; 
EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
var = 20;

DeleteCriticalSection(&cs);
```

Comment: Well, if you've only one thread, how can you think that your thread will wait indefinitely?

Comment: One thread can wait indefinitely, no problem.  It will not in this case because a Windows CS allows recursive locking.